# Configuring Distributed Objects Dynamically

Tags: hazelcast

I'm currently evaluating using Hazelcast for our software. Would be glad if you could help me elucidate the following.

I have one specific requirement: I want to be able to configure distributed objects (say maps, queues, etc.) dynamically. That is, I can't have all the configuration data at hand when I start the cluster. I want to be able to initialise (and dispose) services on-demand, and their configuration possibly to change in-between.

The version I'm evaluating is 3.6.2.

The documentation I have available (Reference Manual, Deployment Guide, as well as the "Mastering Hazelcast" e-book) are very skimpy on details w.r.t. this subject, and even partially contradicting.

So, to clarify an intended usage: I want to start the cluster; then, at some point, create, say, a distributed map structure, use it across the nodes; then dispose it and use a map with a different configuration (say, number of backups, eviction policy) for the same purposes.

The documentation mentions, and this is to be expected, that bad things will happen if nodes have different configurations for the same distributed object. That makes perfect sense and is fine; I can ensure that the configs will be consistent.

Looking at the code, it would seem to be possible to do what I intend: when creating a distributed object, if it doesn't already have a proxy, the HazelcastInstance will go look at its Config to create a new one and store it in its local list of proxies. When that object is destroyed, its proxy is removed from the list. On the next invocation, it would go reload from the Config. Furthermore, that config is writeable, so if it has been changed in-between, it should pick up those changes.

So this would seem like it should work, but given how silent the documentation is on the matter, I'd like some confirmation.

- Is there any reason why the above shouldn't work?
- If it should work, is there any reason *not* to do the above? For instance, are there plans to change the code in future releases in a way that would prevent this from working?
- If so, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the configuration on the fly on an already created Distributed object is not possible with the current version though there is a plan to add this feature in future release. Once created the map configs would stay at node level not at cluster level.
As long as you are creating the Distributed map fresh from the config, using it and destroying it, your approach should work without any issues.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

And yes, I think you should expand Hazelcast in that direction. The fact that right now, configuration is so (at least as the API suggests) static is a bit annoying.